# React Native CLI uses autolinking for native dependencies, but the following modules are linked manually:

Tags: ios, react-native

I am new to react-native ios development. I am getting an error at run time.

error React Native CLI uses autolinking for native dependencies, but the following modules are linked manually:

- react-native-image-picker (to unlink run: "react-native unlink react-native-image-picker")
- react-native-vector-icons (to unlink run: "react-native unlink react-native-vector-icons")
  This is likely happening when upgrading React Native from below 0.60 to 0.60 or above. Going forward, you can unlink this dependency via "react-native unlink " and it will be included in your app automatically. If a library isn't compatible with autolinking, disregard this message and notify the library maintainers.
  Read more about autolinking: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/autolinking.md
  info Found Xcode workspace "Usam.xcworkspace"
  info Building (using "xcodebuild -workspace Usam.xcworkspace -configuration Debug -scheme Usam -destination id=864564F6-8E02-4C19-BFBD-9A798FFD31B2")
  .............................................................................
  error Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65. To debug build logs further, consider building your app with Xcode.app, by opening Usam.xcworkspace. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
  note: Using new build system
  note: Planning build

Answer (score 0):

For me it caused by installing react-native-vector-icons and linking by running the `react-native link react-native-vector-icons` command.

I just unlinked the react-native-vector-icons by following commands

1. `react-native unlink react-native-vector-icons`
2. `cd ios`
3. `pod install`
4. `cd ..`
5. `react-native run-ios`

As I already installed an other icon library.